# How can I fix the string concatenation issue in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

**Here I am concatenating strings in JavaScript**

```
var showList = to_dos =>{
var container = document.querySelector('.work-area .todo-list');
container.innerHTML= "";
for(var i=0; i<to_dos.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML+="<div class='list'>"+
    "<p>"+ to_dos[i].todoContent +"</p>"+
    "<form action='/removeItem' method = 'post' class='icn'> \
        <button type = 'submit' name = "+to_dos[i].todoContent+"><i class='fa fa-check icon check'"+str+"></i></button>\
        <button type = 'submit'><i class='fa fa-close icon close'></i></button>\
    </form>\
</div>"
}
```

}

**But it is doing this thing when I load my Html page**

```
<button type="submit" name="Read" the book ><i class="fa fa-check icon check" onclick="checkComplete(this)"></i></button>
```

*Notice at the name attribute of button tag. Here the content was 'Read the book' but here it only assigns Read to the name attribute and does not assign all the values*
Here it should be the value of name attribute as name = "Read the book". Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: Templates strings would make this much better readable. It would also be helpful to have an example of `to_dos`. My guess is you are just missing the quotes for name: `name='"+to_dos[i].todoContent+"'>`.

Comment: or use any of the numerous very good libraries for templates instead of rolling your own string concatenation